# centos iptables at windows network

Tags: centos, iptables, centos6

I've got a machine, running Centos and it's connected to a windows network. When I try to view the network I'm getting the error "unable to connect share list from server". Once I turned iptables off everything works fine. How ca I fix this problem. My current iptables configuration is

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Sat Nov 16 11:06:35 2013
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [6:360]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.2.0/24 -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 445 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.2.0/24 -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp --dport 445 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.2.0/24 -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp --dport 137 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.2.0/24 -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp --dport 138 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.2.0/24 -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 139 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 
  COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Nov 16 11:06:35 2013
```

Answer (score 0):

You can temporary add the log rule for rejected traffic:

```
-A INPUT -j LOG --log-prefix "Rejected: "
```

before your:

```
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

And you`ll see which traffic is rejected..

Answer (score 0):

a] First log the dropped ip tables for example like this

```
#----------
# Logs to messages.log
#----------
-A INPUT -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables denied: INPUT " --log-level 4
-A OUTPUT -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables denied: OUTPUT " --log-level 4
-A FORWARD -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables denied: FORWARD " --log-level 4
```

b] tail dropped tables from messages

```
tomas@raspirarium:~ $ tail -f /var/log/messages |grep "iptables denied"
```

c] write ip tables rules beyond the denied rules in message.log on the fly as is the example bottom

```
#----------
# Windows Samba
#----------
# incoming request
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -s 192.168.79.0/24 -m multiport --dports 139,445 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -d 192.168.79.0/24 -m multiport --sports 1024:65535 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
# outgoing laso handler
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -s 192.168.79.0/24 -m multiport --dports 139,445 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -s 192.168.79.0/24 -m multiport --sports 1024:65535 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```